# Getting error instead of version for Angular while using the ng --version command

Tags: angular-cli, angular8

Getting error instead of version for Angular while using the ng --version command[image]

Comment: I am using NPM.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the current Angular globally:

`npm uninstall -g angular-cli`

Clean the cache:

`npm cache clean --force`

And install the Angular globally:

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 0):

Check after install the following package

```
npm i @angular-devkit/core
```

Comment: npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\anandkumar\Downloads\ngx-admin-master (1)\ngx-admin-master\node_modules\.staging\echarts-c4b14225\build\.jshintrc'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\anandkumar\Downloads\ngx-admin-master (1)\ngx-admin-master\node_modules\.staging\ng2-completer-64fc670d\esm5\ng2-completer.js'

Comment: Yes i am using theme

Comment: Already you are installed angular? Can you come out from the project folder and check the angular version!

Comment: I came out of the project folder,
Angular CLI: 8.0.2
Node: 10.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.800.2
@angular-devkit/core         8.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.0.2
@schematics/angular          8.0.2
@schematics/update           0.800.2
rxjs                         6.4.0

Comment: No, it is not showing. Please note that next to Angular you can find ....